# Retrieve value from read only screen in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Could you please help me to fetch the value from the read-only screen. I'm using below code. I'm able to fetch value but it shows exact value example.

```
XXXXX4309
```

But I want value without this sign, so please help me:

```
String SSN = driver.findElement(By.id(SSN)).getAttribute(value");
String SSNExpected = "451514309";
Assert.assertEquals(SSN, SSNExpected);
System.out.print("SSN textbox value: " + SSN)`
```

> Output - XXXXX4309

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it's protected. if it's input just protected just by `type="password"` you can change this type by JavaScript(changing type of input field to text for example) execution and get unhidden value

Answer (score 0):

It may help you,

```
        //String SSN=   driver.findElement(By.id(SSN)).getAttribute("value");
        String SSN=(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) this.webDriver).executeScript("angular.element($('#endDate')).text()");
        String SSNActual=SSN.replaceAll("X", "");
        String SSNExpected = "451514309";
        Assert.assertEquals(SSNExpected.contains(SSNActual),true);
```

Comment: <input disabled="" readonly="readonly" type="text" tabindex="1" ng-style="{'font-size':vm.layout.fontsize}" ng-minlength="9" ssn-mask="" ng-model="vm.loanApplication.applicantInformations[0].ssn" id="ssN" name="ssN" maxlength="9" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: are able to get the value from input box?

Comment: you try the following to get value return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) this.webDriver).executeScript("angular.element($('#SSN')).text()");

Comment: how we can use 'this' context, it shows me error for this?